# Фильтрация целочисленной переменной

Tags: php

Как правильно фильтровать?

Так: `$id = abs(num($_GET['id']));`
Или так: `$id = intval($_GET['id']);`

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под фильтрацией? Может вот это вам подойдет? bool is_numeric ( mixed $var )

Comment: Просто каст в инт. Если пользователь указал отрицательное число - это некорректный запрос.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Правильный способ:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Cписок фильтров :
http://php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Подробнее о filter_input: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php